# Safari too slow rendering CSS gradients

Tags: css, safari

I am trying to generate navigation menu gradients dynamically using php using CSS. Safari is way too slow (takes about 20s to load page) on safari, but works fine on other browsers like firefox and chrome.

Here is the code responsible for this:

```
navi .pure-menu-horizontal {

background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#8fc6f3 0%, #e6e9e6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

What exactly is causing this problem?

UPDATE: Seems this line is causing the whole issue. I tried removing this last line

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%); /* W3C */
```

it works fine, but gradient not rendered in other browsers, works fine in safari.

i tried `repeating-linear-gradient` although it works fine but intermittently safari too slow loading..

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8fc6f3 0%,#e6e9e6 100%);
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Safari's rendering engine.

Comment: "still i am not convinced": of what?

Comment: did you test it on iphone or mac?

Comment: yes it finally worked. no problem with the code.